# How to display an NSArray in a UILabel and use timer

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nstimer

I'm trying to display an array of numbers in a UILabel using a timer,and show them in the order set in the array, but I only receive the Title in the format and then a SIGABRT !
any suggestions...Thanks

Part of the code with problems!

```
-(IBAction) rotate3
{
    NSString *number = [dayArray initWithArray:(NSArray *)dayArray];
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"0", @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5" ,@"6", @"7", @"8",@"9",@"10",@"11",@"12",@"13", @"14", @"15", @"16", @"17", @"18", @"19",nil];
    numberCount++;
    timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(rotate3 )userInfo:nil repeats:YES];    
    self.dayArray = array;
    [array release];

    label.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Day %@  " number];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very strange string : `[dayArray initWithArray:(NSArray *)dayArray];`. Try this:

```
-(IBAction) rotate3
{
    NSString *number = [self.dayArray description];
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"0", @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5" ,@"6", @"7", @"8",@"9",@"10",@"11",@"12",@"13", @"14", @"15", @"16", @"17", @"18", @"19",nil];
    numberCount++;
    timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(rotate3 )userInfo:nil repeats:YES];    
    self.dayArray = array;
    [array release];

    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Day %@  ", number];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I stop receiving the SIGABRT warning , the thing now is I have  the full array in the label.text (Day 0,1,2,3...,) and I want to show one by one every 5 sec. What did I type wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your SIGABRT is probably due to stack corruption: NSTimer can only be used with selectors of the form:

```
- (void)myTimerFireMethod: (NSTimer *)timer;
```

but you're trying to use it with

```
- (void)rotate3;
```

which doesn't take enough arguments.

Comment: Now I moved the timer after - (void) didLoad where the other timers are. I dont know if it's workin due to the full array display.