# Display NSMutableArray in UIlabel in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I have to display NSmutableArray data in UIlabel .But only the last index text is getting added .Here is my code

```
marray:
(
{ 
ID=1;
}
{
ID="2"
}
)

 for(int i=0;i<[marray count];i++)
    {
        eventName=[[arr2 objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Code"];
       label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID :%@",eventName ];        
    }
```

I have to display these ID's in UIlabel with text as :  1 , 2

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try the below Code. 
NSString *temp=@"";
for(int i=0;i<[marray count];i++)
    {

        //eventName=[[arr2 objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Code"];
        temp=[temp stringByAppendingString:[[arr2 objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Code"]];

        temp=[temp stringByAppendingString:@" ,"];
    } 
 temp = [temp substringToIndex:[temp length]-1];
label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID :%@",temp ];
```

Comment: .I got it working partially .I want in this format 1 , 2.i.e a space and comma after each item

Comment: Check my edited Answer if it is useful plz accept it my clicking on checkmark and upvote by up arrow

Comment: Thanks I got it. I have a small question .Here if I have more Ids like 3,4,5,6 ...then am unable to see it in label .that part is cut .so if I want to display content in such a away that if its not sufficient in the first line then it should be displayed in the next line and so on....How can I do it ?this is the label I m doing  label=[[UILabel alloc]init];
    [label setFrame:CGRectMake(20,175,330, 60)];
    label.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
    label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

Comment: You can make multiLine label. yourLable.numberofLines=10; then increase the height of label. or you can use UITextView for scrolling Label does not scroll you need to increase the height according to your data.

Comment: And you can use the description method of NSSArray to get all contents in string by  NSString *arrContents=[arr description];

Comment: You can upvote my answer on clicking up Arrow just above 0 digit

Comment: K I dont have sufficient reputation to upvote ur answer.I have checked it now in ur code Im getting comma after 2 .i.e  1,2, I shouldnot get this comma after 2..How ?

Answer (score 1):

You are running a for loop which will continue executing till its last increment . So the last value in the array would be displayed. So what you can do is that you can add a timer instead of a for loop that is if you want to show your `NSmutableArray` as changing in the `UILabel`.

**EDIT:**

```
-(IBAction) rotate3
{
    NSString *number = [self.dayArray description];
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"0", @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5" ,@"6", @"7", @"8",@"9",@"10",@"11",@"12",@"13", @"14", @"15", @"16", @"17", @"18", @"19",nil];
    numberCount++;
    timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(rotate3 )userInfo:nil repeats:YES];    
    self.dayArray = array;
    [array release];

    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Day %@  ", number];
}
```

Also check these links [How to update UILabel programmatically in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884786/how-to-update-uilabel-programmatically-in-ios) and [How to display an NSArray in a UILabel and use timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018688/how-to-display-an-nsarray-in-a-uilabel-and-use-timer)

Comment: But I want all the items of NSMutableArray in label's text>How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

you can append string to NSString object than use that object in label like bellow

```
NSMutableString *lblstr=@"ID :";

for (int i=0; i<[marray count]; i++) {
    eventName=[[arr2 objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Code"];
    [lblstr appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",eventName ]];
}
label.text=lblstr;
```

Comment: Appending the string wont help it being displayed coz the for loop runs pretty fast doesn't it ?

Comment: I m getting error at this line [lblstr appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",eventName ]];.Program received SIGABRT ..IN console area I can see "Attempt to mutate immutable object with appendString:'"What shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

for(int i=0;i<[marray count];i++)
{
   NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d - %@\n",i+1, [[arr2 objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Code"]];

  [str appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",temp]];

   //sleep(0.05); //Remove comment this line may help ! **Tricky Line**
}

label.text = str;

[str release];
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create an array of objects (indexes) and use `componentsJoinedByString:`

`NSString* str = [array componentsJoindeByString: @", "];`

Or using your code, replacing

```
label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID :%@",eventName ];
```

with:

```
label.text=[label.text stringByAppendingFormat:@", %@", eventName];
```